Can the ability to sign arbitrary messages expose the private key?
Consider a system that consists of a black box (some abstraction layer with perfect sandboxing). The black box contains a private key that cannot be extracted by request, but the black box exposes an interface where that private key can be used to produce a digital signature for any message handed to it.
In other words, the box exposes these functions with the interface (written in Rust
programming language syntax)
fn sign_message(message: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>;
fn verify_signature(message: Vec<u8>, signature: Vec<u8>) -> bool;

So the box can produce signatures from the internal private key and and can verify signatures too with a boolean answer, stating whether the signature is correct (sure we can expose the public key, but that's beyond the point as it doesn't matter).
Note: the box is capable of producing true random numbers, if needed, for the signatures.
The question: Can someone, given this interface, practically extract the private key, by choosing an arbitrary set of messages and attempting to find a relationship between the signatures produced?
This question is asked in the context of secp256k1 curve signatures (whether Schnorr signatures or not), but I'd love to know if there's a general answer to this problem.
Why asking? I'm designing an authentication hardware that does digital signatures, and I'm wondering whether it's worth the effort to isolate certain parts of that systems, by not giving them access to private keys, but only ability to get signatures on arbitrary messages.

Your interfaces resemble two oracles utilized in security reduction, and do not reveal the private key and verification key. I believe that well-established signature schemes, such as ECDSA, EDDSA, etc., can withstand CMA-EUF and CMA-SUF attacks. If you know the two attacks, the answer is no.

@X.H.Yue Thank you for the explanation. Are there signature schemes used widely that suffer from these kinds of attacks? Is there a list of schemes or something, so that I can be aware of it?

Two more considerations: 1) do you allow access to the sign interface freely? 2) What is the quality of the random? ECDSA is vulnerable to tiny bias

@kelalaka Yes, access to the interface is freely available to the sandboxed plugin using it. The RNG I'm planning to use is this one from rust. It does implement CryptoRng, which means it's considered cryptographically secure. Internally it uses ChaCha12 with periodic reseeding.

Isn't that someone can use the sign access and use it against you?

@kelalaka There are two things to be taken into account. First, the process can be (ab)used only during a single signature process on a hardware device, so this protects from future attacks when the attacker doesn't know the private key, if an attacker can't transfer the key to use it later. Second, there are more complex considerations related to how this private key is derived. Under certain circumstances, knowing one private key will expose a series of private key, due to using BIP-44 for deriving keys combined with soft derivations.
